# Why aren't all dictionary items returned?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
print ("Welcome to International Football Transfers")
inpt = raw_input("Do you want to buy player or sell?")

def lst_of_players():
    if inpt == "buy":
        print ("Here is list of players and their prices")
    players = {
    'Paul Pogba' : '$89,3m',
    'Gareth Bale' : '$85,3m',
    'Cristiano Ronaldo' : '$80m',
    'Gonzalo Higuain' : '$75,3m',
    'James Rodriguez' : '$79,8m',
    'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' : '$56m',
    'Kaka' : '$50m'
    }
    for keys, values in players.items():      #Printing keys and values from dictionary
        return (keys, values)
    print (keys,values)

plyrs = lst_of_players()
print (plyrs)
```

Problem is when I type `"buy"` in `raw_input`, the output I get is:

```
Welcome to International Football Transfers
Do you want to buy player or sell?buy
Here is list of players and their prices
('Kaka', '$50m')

***Repl Closed***
```

My question is why do I get output just for `Kaka` and not for all the other players?

Comment: you are returning the first key value in your loop, maybe store them or print them directly

Comment: You need to pass inpt as a parameter

Comment: `return` in Python finishes the whole function, you should rather store the values in a list.

Comment: Have you studied python?

Comment: I'm studying python at home, i finished codeacademy python course, studying at youtube, practicepython, and i'm coding everyday. If you have some learning tips for me, text me. @PedroLobito

Comment: Search for function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your input to the file and print the results instead of returning them.

```
 def lst_of_players(inpt):       
    if inpt == "buy":      
        print ("Here is list of players and their prices")
        players = {
       'Paul Pogba' : '$89,3m',
       'Gareth Bale' : '$85,3m',
       'Cristiano Ronaldo' : '$80m',
       'Gonzalo Higuain' : '$75,3m',
       'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' : '$56m',
       'Kaka' : '$50m'
        }
       for keys, values in players.items():  

          print (keys,values)



print ("Welcome to International Football Transfers")
inpt = raw_input("Do you want to buy player or sell?")
lst_of_players(inpt)
```

Comment: just lacks the function parameter

Comment: You need to make inpt a parameter

Answer (score 1):

When your `return` statement is evaluated inside of the `lst_of_players` function, the function returns what is specified, and the function is exited - so your `print (keys,values)` isn't being executed.

From what I can tell, what you are trying to achieve may be implemented as:

```
print ("Welcome to International Football Transfers")
inpt = raw_input("Do you want to buy player or sell?")

def lst_of_players():
    if inpt == "buy":
        print ("Here is list of players and their prices")
    players = {
    'Paul Pogba' : '$89,3m',
    'Gareth Bale' : '$85,3m',
    'Cristiano Ronaldo' : '$80m',
    'Gonzalo Higuain' : '$75,3m',
    'James Rodriguez' : '$79,8m',
    'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' : '$56m',
    'Kaka' : '$50m'
    }
    for key, value in players.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))

lst_of_players()
```

Answer (score 1):

You made some mistakes in your script:

- You never use `inpt` as a paramater of your function, so you need to
  add that to your function.
- When returning a value, the function is terminated, you rather need
  to call `print` inside the `for` loop.
- Finally, you only need to call your function, there's no need to
  assign your function to a variable and then print it like your last
  lines of code do.

Try somethink like this:

```
def lst_of_players(inpt):
    if inpt == "buy":
        print ("Here is list of players and their prices")
    players = {
    'Paul Pogba' : '$89,3m',
    'Gareth Bale' : '$85,3m',
    'Cristiano Ronaldo' : '$80m',
    'Gonzalo Higuain' : '$75,3m',
    'James Rodriguez' : '$79,8m',
    'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' : '$56m',
    'Kaka' : '$50m'
    }
    for key, value in players.items():
        print(key, value)

lst_of_players(inpt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for keys, values in players.items():      #Printing keys and values from dictionary
        return (keys, values) #Does this ONCE
```

The function terminates once return is used. It will return the first set of keys and values it loops through. Therefore, you will only get output for one player. As the second answer says, you can print them instead of returning them. You could also append them to a list and return the list. Also, you need to pass inpt as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score -1):

try using lists, instead of dictionaries. for example:

```html
players = ['Paul Pogba : $89,3m',
    'Gareth Bale : $85,3m',
    'Cristiano Ronaldo : $80m',
    'Gonzalo Higuain : $75,3m',
    'James Rodriguez : $79,8m',
    'Zlatan Ibrahimovic : $56m',
    'Kaka : $50m']
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax in python. It's also not clear how this answers the question.